# Angular Reactive form weird behavior

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have this code I'm working on:

login.component.html

```html
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="./assets/icons/login.png" alt="Login">
        <p>Login in to your account</p>
    </div>
        <form [formGroup]="form" class="login" (ngSubmit)="onClick()">
            <p class="error-message" style="font-size: large;" *ngIf="!isValid">Please fill the your info</p>
            <p>Enter your user name and password</p>
            <div class="userName">
                <label for="userName">User name</label>
                <br>
                <input [ngClass]="{'error': emailValidation && !isValid}" type="text" id="userName" placeholder="Your user name" formControlName="email">
                <p class="error-message" *ngIf="emailValidation && !isValid">please enter your user name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pass">
                <label for="pass">Password</label>
                <br>
                <input [ngClass]="{'error': passwordValidation || !isValid}" type="password" id="pass" placeholder="your password" formControlName="password">
                <p class="error-message" *ngIf="passwordValidation || !isValid">please enter your user password</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btnConfig" id="btnlogin"><img src="./assets/icons/login-btn.png" alt="login"> Login</button>
        </form>             
</div>
```

login.component.ts:

```
import { AfterContentChecked, Component, DoCheck, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, DoCheck {
  form!: FormGroup;
  isValid: boolean = true;

  constructor (private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe()
  }


  ngDoCheck(): void {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.isValid = this.form.valid;
    });  
  }

  get emailValidation() {
    return this.form.get('email')?.invalid || this.form.get('email')?.touched;
  }

  get passwordValidation() {
    return this.form.get('password')?.invalid && this.form.get('password')?.touched;
  }


  onClick() {
    if(this.form.valid) {
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard']);
    } else {
      this.isValid = this.form.valid;
    }
  }
}
```

[Live preview](https://ahmadallan.github.io/School-System/)

Everything works fine with the validation until I press the login button with the two input fields empty the error message shows. And when I just fill one of the input the error messages disappears from both fields.

I tried

```
ngDoCheck(): void {
    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
      this.isValid = this.form.valid;
    });  
  }
```

to keep checking but still the bug doesn't go.

Comment: live preview link not working

Comment: Your preview is not working.

Comment: i fixed the live preview

Comment: on every doCheck you are subscribing to your form and never unsubscribing. Put the subscription in your oninit and remove the docheck part completely.

Comment: For me everything is working fine, I did your same test (press the login button with the two input fields empty the error message show and when i just fill one of the input the error messages disappear from both fields)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i fix the problem by remove the ngDoCheck, put the subscription in to ngOnInit,
replace the isVaild with isSubmitted, edit the passwordValidation and emailValidation, and edit the OnClick to be onSubmit

login.component.ts:

```
    import { AfterContentChecked, Component, DoCheck, OnChanges, OnInit, SimpleChanges } from '@angular/core';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import {  Router } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  form!: FormGroup;
  isSubmitted: boolean = false;

  constructor (private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      email: ['', Validators.required],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.form.valueChanges.subscribe()
  }

  get emailValidation() {
    return this.form.get('email')?.invalid && (this.form.get('email')?.dirty || this.form.get('email')?.touched || this.isSubmitted);
  }

  get passwordValidation() {
    return this.form.get('password')?.invalid && (this.form.get('password')?.dirty || this.form.get('password')?.touched || this.isSubmitted);
  }


  onSubmit(): void {
    if(this.form.valid){
      this.router.navigate(['/dashboard'])
    }
    this.isSubmitted = true;
  }
}
```

login.component.html:

```
<div class="main">
    <div class="image">
        <img src="./assets/icons/login.png" alt="Login">
        <p>Login in to your account</p>
    </div>
        <form [formGroup]="form" class="login" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
            <p class="error-message" style="font-size: large;" *ngIf="isSubmitted">Please fill the your info</p>
            <p>Enter your user name and password</p>
            <div class="userName">
                <label for="userName">User name</label>
                <br>
                <input [ngClass]="{'error': emailValidation}" type="text" id="userName" placeholder="Your user name" formControlName="email">
                <p class="error-message" *ngIf="emailValidation">please enter your user name</p>
            </div>
            <div class="pass">
                <label for="pass">Password</label>
                <br>
                <input [ngClass]="{'error': passwordValidation}" type="password" id="pass" placeholder="your password" formControlName="password">
                <p class="error-message" *ngIf="passwordValidation">please enter your user password</p>
            </div>
            <button class="btnConfig" id="btnlogin" type="submit"><img src="./assets/icons/login-btn.png" alt="login"> Login</button>
        </form>             
</div>
```

Comment: you still never unsubscribe from your subscription. read up on this, this can lead to bad performance and weird side effects if you never unsubscribe from stuff like this.